# How to force the Fully Qualified Domain Name in Browser using IIS7

Tags: iis, internet-explorer-11, windows-server-2008-r2, fqdn

Currently we have a website called sitename.domain.com. For many reasons that will not be mentioned we implemented IE 11 and now we found an issue with some users typing http://sitename instead of http://sitename.domain.com . While this should be fine, what is happening is that when they go to the site the saddress bar says http://sitename, we need it to say http://sitename.domain.com . Now this is an internal website, how can we force the full name. When we pint the sitename it shows the full name sitename.domain.com yet in the browser address bar when we type http://sitename it just goes to sitename not sitename.domain.com . Without redirection how can we fix this in IIS 7?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in website bindings there is no binding with empty host name. Ideally there should be only one binding there with fully qualified domain name.